# Using TMSSignatureCapture component for FMX image saves as black background in android

Tags: android, delphi, tms

I am using `TMSSignatureCapture` Component but when am trying to save the signature the  image save as black black back-grounded image
I used below code in the FMX form to save the  image  , but it saves as black back-grounded png image in the android.

```
SignatureCapture.SaveToFile('/sdcard/Signatures/Signfilee_Android.png',true);
```

Iam trying to save the image  in a white background with black ink for the signature, but android saves as black backgrounded image, is there anyway to remove the black background and make it white?

Comment: Does it work on other platforms? It sounds like you need to consult the vendor.

Comment: Try clearing/filling the canvas first to white.

Comment: Definitely consult the vendor.